# Correcting for spillover bias in experiments?

Tags: regression, experiment-design, medicine, bias-correction

Suppose I have an experiment designed where I'm interested in observing the effect of daily walking on self-reported joint pain in elderly adults. The population of interest are elderly adults who reportedly do not partake in daily walking who have noticeable, self-reported joint pain. I've randomized, started, collected data, and I'm ready to analyze my experiment.

Originally, I had planned to model the results as such where the binary variables, (treatment) group and (time) period have a product of 1 if an exposure occurred (treatment group during the post-start period.)

$$ pain_i = \beta_1*group_i + \beta_2*period_i + \beta_3*(group_i * period_i)  $$

Looking at the observed data, very few adults in the treatment group have walked *every* day. Most have walked between 3-5 days. Fortunately, no members of the control group have done any walking during the experiment.

As such, I want to account for varying levels of exposure where the level could be the average number of days walking per week. Or alternatively, level could be the total weekly minutes spent walking. (Or the log minutes spent walking because if someone theoretically had spent an arbitrarily high number of minutes walking, the regression model might predict a negative pain.)

$$ pain_i = \beta_1*group_i + \beta_2*period_i + \beta_3*level_i  $$

One could argue that I should still consider exposure as a binary variable, but then I would be studying the effect of some walking, perhaps not daily or even weekly, which is not the research question.

To answer this question, please address 1/ whether varying levels of exposure is a reliable means to address such bias 2/ if this proposed solution is viable and 3/ (if not viable) what should I do instead or where can I read more if solution space is too expansive to capture in a single Q/A.

Comment: Can I ask a clarifying question: why are you studying daily walking? The reason I ask is because it seems to me that, if the practical problem you are trying to solve is reducing joint pain, you should test the efficacy of the intervention, not individual's response to the intervention. Therefore, what matters is not how many days they actually walk, but whether their joint pain changes as a result of you *prompting* them to walk. So I'd keep exposure as binary, at least in your primary analysis. This tells you how an intervention designed to improve joint pain works. Then, at least in my fiel

Comment: This is not a case of spillover bias. Your question deals with how to measure an exposure. An objective clinical measure of physical activity is the METS https://www.healthline.com/health/what-are-mets#met-goals. Going about inventing an encoding of the activity level as you have measured it has a low level of reproducibility.

Comment: There is however a strong case for suspecting that pain and walking have a complex confounding. That is daily pain prior to walking is probably more likely to predict non-compliance than walking is to predict pain as a response to moderate physical activity. If you don't adjust for baseline pain, this analysis really can't add up to much.

Comment: So I don’t really have walking data or elderly adults. This is a metaphor for an experiment that involves proprietary / confidential product at a technology company. But the varying levels of exposure problem is indeed present.